# how to list all processes as sorted names

Tags: 14.04, process, ps

As far as I know, `ps -e`will list all processes in ubuntu. But the results are sorted based on `pid`. I want the results are based on sorted names. What command should I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an optional `--sort=` specifier e.g.

```
 ps -e --sort=args
```

From `man ps`

```
   --sort spec     Specify sorting order. Sorting syntax is
                   [+|-]key[,[+|-]key[,...]]. Choose a multi-letter key
                   from the STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS section.
```